# High Volume, High Speed Textbox in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, windows, textbox, serial-port

I am writing an application that will display **serial/USB data** at a rate of up to **250kb/sec**. I am using the .net **SerialPort** class and reacting to the `DataReceived` event. For early implementations of this software, I simply stored the incoming data in a **WinForms `RichTextBox`**. This solution works fine until there are **50k - 100k lines** in the control, at which point the application bogs down. Since then, I've tried accomplishing my goals with **WPF** and found the same problem. I tried, at one point, to keep only the **currently visible text** in the textbox, and store the rest in a **large `List<string>`** but this solution required a huge number of workarounds and, in the end, was abandoned - **I'd rather not reinvent the wheel**.

Now I come to you for a thread of hope - I am willing to try **anything**! Should I use a **custom control** (both pay and free controls are welcome)? **SQLite**? **Virtualization** as described above? Should I try **polling the SerialPort** instead of reacting to events?

Comment: Can your users keep up with 250 kb/sec ?

Comment: Why you need to show if any human can read at this speed? I think the best  is write direct to file. Maybe show last lines at a TextBox

Comment: 250kb/sec is the theoretical maximum we should ever have to deal with. The actual data rate is usually less than half this rate.

Comment: I really hope you use green letters flowing down on the screen ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a thread to read the data and write it directly to a file.  Have your app refresh the last x number of lines from the file every so often.  Maybe even have the refresh based off of a notification from the reader thread?

By using multiple threads you'll keep the UI responsive and by writing straight to a file you'll ensure you've collected all of the data.  Also, it will allow you to pause the display long enough to actually copy/paste the data you want while continuing to capture data.

Possibly you could implement your own type of file reader that would allow the user to "scroll" through the file by only loading the parts you can actually display on screen at one time.

Answer (score 4):

If the data is largely line oriented (ReadLine) then put it in a ListBox. It is the fastest control for putting lots of text onscreen.

But you will find that all UI controls are geared toward human interaction, not to the speed of a Port. Best thing to do would be to rethink your design. What is that data for anyway?

Comment: The application is for realtime viewing of a vehicle data bus. Generally, we need to see the data character by character. The reason I haven't tried a listbox is because we often need to copy text from the application.

Comment: @CWMan: You can copy text from a ListBox; just add a context menu or handle a Ctrl+C keystroke (or both, or whatever mechanism you like for copying text) and copy it to the clipboard yourself.